# From within a cakephp model is there a way in the to find out which validation failed?

Tags: cakephp

I wonder if there is a way, in the model, to find out which validation failed, something like the validate() method in the controller.

The reason I'm asking this is, is because I was writing a method in a model that doesn't need a controller. The method always failed and I suspected that it was due to the validation. The only way I could think to find out, was to remove the validation, or write a controller and do a validate() with the data.

Comment: pr($this); you will learn a lot by reading the contents of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->invalidFields();
```

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelinvalidFields